# print &nbsp; inside postLink with CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

i was wondering if there's any way to print " " inside a postLink element using CakePHP.

I want to get something like this:

```
<a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

And trying this:

```
'.$this->Form->postLink(nl2br("&nbsp;"), array('action'=> 'xxxx')).'
```

I get this instead:

```
<a href="#">&amp;nbsp;</a>
```

Which prints me   inside the link instead of printing a white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since postLink() is nothing else than a special wrapper for link() there should also be `escape`

```
$this->Form->postLink(nl2br('&nbsp;'), array('action' => 'xxxx'), array('escape' => false));
```

see https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1582